# Fast replicated random sampling from raster

Tags: r, performance, loops, spatial, r-raster

I have to iterate 1000 times a random sampling of a point per grid polygon in a raster for grid sizes from 5 to 25.
With a raster 50 x 50 (2500 cells) the process takes more than 1h with the following code:

```
library(raster)
library(dplyr)

# This is the script for random sampling inside the grid cells
sample_grid <- function(r, w, n){

  grid <- raster(extent(r))
  res(grid) <- w
  proj4string(grid) <- proj4string(r)
  gridpolygon <- rasterToPolygons(grid)

  pickpts <- sapply(gridpolygon@polygons, spsample, n = n, type = "random")
  sapply(pickpts, FUN = extract, x = r)
}

# Let's make a raster
r <- raster(ncol = 50, nrow = 50, xmn = 0, xmx = 50, ymn = 0, ymx = 50)
values(r) <- runif(ncell(r))

# Repeat the random sampling process 1000 times for different grid sizes
sapply(5:25, function(x) replicate(1000, sample_grid(r, x, 1) %>% 
                                               mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

I would like to make it faster. A reasonable target would be about 15 minutes.
Do you have any suggestions?

This is the output for `Rprof`

```
Rprof(tmp <- tempfile())
sample_grid(r, 10, 1) %>% mean(., na.rm = TRUE)
Rprof()
summaryRprof(tmp)

#################### summaryRprof output ####################
$by.self
                     self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
"eval"                    0.02    14.29       0.14    100.00
"initialize"              0.02    14.29       0.06     42.86
"getClassDef"             0.02    14.29       0.04     28.57
".getClassFromCache"      0.02    14.29       0.02     14.29
"aperm"                   0.02    14.29       0.02     14.29
"merge.data.frame"        0.02    14.29       0.02     14.29
"validityMethod"          0.02    14.29       0.02     14.29

$by.total
                      total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
"eval"                     0.14    100.00      0.02    14.29
"%>%"                      0.14    100.00      0.00     0.00
".local"                   0.14    100.00      0.00     0.00
"FUN"                      0.14    100.00      0.00     0.00
"lapply"                   0.14    100.00      0.00     0.00
"sample_grid"              0.14    100.00      0.00     0.00
"sapply"                   0.14    100.00      0.00     0.00
"standardGeneric"          0.14    100.00      0.00     0.00
"initialize"               0.06     42.86      0.02    14.29
"new"                      0.06     42.86      0.00     0.00
"getClassDef"              0.04     28.57      0.02    14.29
".cellValues"              0.04     28.57      0.00     0.00
".readCells"               0.04     28.57      0.00     0.00
".xyValues"                0.04     28.57      0.00     0.00
"CRS"                      0.04     28.57      0.00     0.00
"over"                     0.04     28.57      0.00     0.00
"sample.Polygon"           0.04     28.57      0.00     0.00
"validObject"              0.04     28.57      0.00     0.00
".getClassFromCache"       0.02     14.29      0.02    14.29
"aperm"                    0.02     14.29      0.02    14.29
"merge.data.frame"         0.02     14.29      0.02    14.29
"validityMethod"           0.02     14.29      0.02    14.29
".bboxCoords"              0.02     14.29      0.00     0.00
".uniqueNames"             0.02     14.29      0.00     0.00
"["                        0.02     14.29      0.00     0.00
"anyStrings"               0.02     14.29      0.00     0.00
"apply"                    0.02     14.29      0.00     0.00
"as.matrix"                0.02     14.29      0.00     0.00
"identical"                0.02     14.29      0.00     0.00
"identicalCRS"             0.02     14.29      0.00     0.00
"is"                       0.02     14.29      0.00     0.00
"match.arg"                0.02     14.29      0.00     0.00
"merge"                    0.02     14.29      0.00     0.00
"merge.default"            0.02     14.29      0.00     0.00
"names"                    0.02     14.29      0.00     0.00
"SpatialPolygons"          0.02     14.29      0.00     0.00
"stopifnot"                0.02     14.29      0.00     0.00
"t"                        0.02     14.29      0.00     0.00
"table"                    0.02     14.29      0.00     0.00
"validNames"               0.02     14.29      0.00     0.00

$sample.interval
[1] 0.02

$sampling.time
[1] 0.14
###############################################################
```

Comment: Looks like the last two steps in `sample_grid` can be done in the same `sapply` call. Have you profiled the function to see what really takes long?

Comment: I have added the output of `summaryRprof`.